# MediaPlayer works in Android, but progress does not

Tags: java, android, android-mediaplayer, seekbar

I've been working on this for a while, trying to get this tutorial to work (http://united-coders.com/nico-heid/an-android-seekbar-for-your-mediaplayer/), but I haven't had any luck. The audio playback works perfect, but the SeekBar doesn't move.

```
package com.example.playingaudio;

import java.io.FileInputStream;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.media.AudioManager;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.SeekBar;

public class MainActivity extends Activity implements Runnable {

    private MediaPlayer mediaPlayer;
    private SeekBar progress;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        progress = (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.seekBar1);

    }

    public void playButton(View view) {
        try {
            playRecording();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    protected void playRecording() throws Exception {
        final MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
        FileInputStream fileStream = new FileInputStream(
                "/sdcard/Download/mySong.mp3");
        mediaPlayer.setDataSource(fileStream.getFD());
        mediaPlayer.prepare(); // might take long! (for buffering, etc)
        mediaPlayer.start();
        run();
    }

    private void ditchMediaPlayer() {
        if (mediaPlayer != null) {
            try {
                mediaPlayer.release();

            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        // mp is your MediaPlayer
        // progress is your ProgressBar

        int currentPosition = 0;
        int total = mediaPlayer.getDuration();
        progress.setMax(total);
        while (mediaPlayer != null && currentPosition < total) {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(1000);
                currentPosition = mediaPlayer.getCurrentPosition();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                return;
            } catch (Exception e) {
                return;
            }
            progress.setProgress(currentPosition);
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Why you are doing Thread.sleep() on UI-thread, at first place? That's soooooooooooo bad! God damn so bad!

Comment: I was trying to follow the tutorial.

Comment: Can you share your layout too

Answer (score 1):

Try changing this line

```
final MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
```

To, this line

```
mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
```

The reason is you already have a class variable mediaPlayer declared and why are you declaring the local variable again with the same name.

Answer (score 0):

The reason your bar is not updating is because you aren't giving it a chance to. You have a constant loop on your UI thread that consists mostly of `sleep()`. You can't do that and expect the UI to update.

If you look at that tutorial more closely, you'll see that they don't call `runOnUiThread()`. In fact, at the bottom there is a [link back to SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4641115/android-seekbar-setprogress-is-causing-my-mediaplayer-to-skip), which shows a bit more of the code involved. There's just a new `Thread` created, and `start()` is run. Nothing too tricky.

---

**Example:**

(call this method after `mediaPlayer.start()`):

```
private void createProgressThread() {   
    progressUpdater = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            //...
            //...
        }
    };
    Thread thread = new Thread(progressUpdater);
    thread.start();
}
```

Comment: I switched up my code, I'm not streaming, just playing back a file now. So you can disregard any of the streaming code. The file is local, and it plays fine.

Comment: If you "switched up your code", it would be good to edit the question to reflect the *exact* code you're using. You can't debug by looking at fake code.

Comment: Yeah, I saw that link, but I still don't understand where that "run" code is supposed to be placed. I've updated my question to show how I originally tried to do it.

Comment: That still calls it on the UI thread. You need a new `Thread` to run it on. See code example in update.

Comment: What is `progressUpdater`?

Comment: It's a [Runnable](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/Runnable.html) object. The second line in the example is where it's assigned. If you're not familiar with runnables and threads, you might want to do some reading.