# By using seekBar.setProgress() in Handler the audio becomes slow for my audio player app in android

Tags: android, android-appcompat, runnable, seekbar

I am using **AppCompatSeekBar.**

Everything is working fine Except when I add **seekBar.setProgress()** in Runnable of activity than the audio becomes slow.

```
  private final Runnable mUpdateTimeTask = new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        if (!stopProgressRunnable) {
            int curDur = playerService.getCurrentTrackProgress();
            int totDur = playerService.getCurrentTrackDuration();
            if(seekBar!=null) {
               seekBar.setProgress(curDur);
                currentDur.setText(durationCalculator(curDur));
                TotalDur.setText(durationCalculator(totDur));
            }
            mHandler.postDelayed(this, 1000);
        }
    }
};
```

Here is the seekBar in Layout file.

```
   <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatSeekBar
                            android:id="@+id/seekbar"
                            android:layout_width="0dp"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_gravity="center"
                            android:layout_weight="1"
                            android:padding="4dp"
                            android:progress="30" />
```

And I am updating **seekBar.setMax()** as soon as song changes . So that is not a  problem.

Comment: yes I am sure @pskink

Comment: yes it works perfectly after removing seekBar.setProgress(curDur);

Comment: Does this solve your issue? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4641115/android-seekbar-setprogress-is-causing-my-mediaplayer-to-skip